# require is not defined in angular

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I am using angularjs where i have created a js file(loginCtrl.js) and i have inclused a controller.
I have defined my db connection and schema in another file(server.js) and i want to include that file in my js.

My loginCtrl.js looks like:

```
test.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, loginService){

   $scope.login = function(user)
   {
       console.log('inside function 1');
       var user = require('./server.js')
      console.log('inside function');
       loginService.login(user);
   }

});
```

and my server.js files looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/userregistration');

var userSchema = {
    username: String,
    firstname:String,
    lastname: String,
    email: String,
    password: String
}

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'user');
```

When i run the code, it gives the error like:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

It is printing the console.log defined above.

Comment: your `server.js` file is run by NodeJs, not your browser, right ?

Comment: @meriadec: How can i confirm this?

Comment: if you type `node server.js` in your terminal you are running it with node, if you included the `server.js` script in your browser, you should remove it :)

Comment: @meriadec: How to make this working, so that i can include that in my js file...

Comment: You could never connect with mongo in your browser. It is server side scripting.

Answer (score 7):

`require()` is a NodeJS function, your angular controller will be executed in the browser, which doesn't have that built-in function. If you want to replicate that behavior client-side, you should look at [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)

Comment: Its actually a function from commonjs/systemjs